# Getting a query result whiting a group by

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to get some result of a query. The table stock information about which page in a website visited by a user. So I can have in a row user that visit page "A" per example and a second row with the same user who visit the page "B". I want to do a query that select the user or users who visit the page "A" and "B". I can’t make a “and” in my where condition because there are just one column.

There is the table structure

```
ID | user_id | page | views
1      1        A        44
2      1        B       120
3      2        A       140
4      3        A        22
```

I have try this but doesn't work

```
SELECT users.name,users.id,users.email
                        FROM users
                        JOIN help_messages ON users.id = help_messages.id_user
                        WHERE (PAGE LIKE  '%clubs%' or PAGE like '%profile%') and views >= 1
                        GROUP BY help_messages.id_user, help_messages.page
```

So any solutions please. Thanks

Comment: page is only ever like 'a' or 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach to this uses aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from table t
group by user_id
having sum(page = 'A') > 0 and sum(page = 'B') > 0;
```

The first condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that have an `'A'` and only allows `user_id`s that have at least one such row.  The second condition does the same for `'B'`.

This is a general approach because it is easy to add additional pages.  Also, if you want someone who visited 'A' but not 'B', you would just use:

```
having sum(page = 'A') > 0 and sum(page = 'B') = 0;
```

Comment: i've try to adapted to my data and i've done this query but it's return no result : `SELECT users.name,page,views
FROM users
JOIN help_messages ON users.id = help_messages.id_user
GROUP BY help_messages.id_user,help_messages.page
having (page LIKE  '%homepage%' and views = 1) and (page like '%profile%' and views  =1)`

Comment: @KANDROIDOS . . . Look at the conditions.  They use `sum()`.  Fix your query and it should work.